# Calling the script from script in perl

Tags: perl

I want to call the perl script through the another perl script. I have used,

```
system('/home/arun/title_verifier.pl');
```

but it throws,

```
sh: 1: /home/arun/title_verifier.pl: Permission denied
```

So how can i make it...

Comment: Do you (or the perl script executing) have +x right on the .pl file?

Comment: "+x" means, cant get you? sorry.

Comment: Each linux file has file permissions (do `ls -al` to see them). The basic ones are +rwx, meaning "read permission", "write permission", "execute permission". If a file has +x, you can execute it (call it using its filename, /home/arun/title_verifier.pl. If it does not have +x, you cannot execute it as a program, but you can have another program use it as input for executing, in this example with `perl /home/arun/title_verifier.pl`

Comment: Thank you...its a good learning to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the Perl script has execute permission

```
chmod +x /home/arun/title_verifier.pl
```

or invoke the script with `perl`

```
system('perl /home/arun/title_verifier.pl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you may run it not with environment perl, but with perl your script was run

system($^X, "/home/arun/title_verifier.pl") == 0 or die "$!";